# How do I take care of Apps that need my attention in the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notifications

I have an ultrawide setup, so usually I have two windows side by side at a time. Sometimes, especially with Zoom and Discord, I get many notifications. Whenever I get many messages or notifications the taskbar appears and doesn't disappear until I click on the app to take care of those notifications (like the zoom chat). How can I make it so that the taskbar doesn't appear everytime an app needs my attention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Windows 10 allows you to temporarily [mute all notifications using *Focus Assist*](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-turn-off-notifications-in-windows-10/), both pop-up and in taskbar, useful, for example, when in online meetings or viewing video.

- Click on the *Notifications* icon in the Taskbar.
- Select *Manage notifications* at the top.
- Select *Focus assist* and change settings as you would.

[image: Focus Assist Settings]

Second, the Taskbar can be **completely hidden** using the third-party tool, [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10). **Caveat** Use this tool with caution; some changes may make your PC difficult to use.

[image: Ultimate Windows Tweaker - Taskbar removal]

Third, you can [increase its transparency](https://www.techjunkie.com/windows-10-taskbar-transparency/), e.g., to 100 %, change its position or reduce its height (or width, if vertical).

- To change transparency, in newer versions of Windows, you'll need the add-ons [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net/) (no longer under development, but still work) or its descendant, [Open Shell Menu](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/). Under *Settings* | *Taskbar* tab, set *Taskbar look* to *Transparent* , *Taskbar opacity* to *0*, and select colors to make it as unobtrusive as possible. Icons *will* still show, though.
- [To change the size and position of the Taskbar](https://www.howtogeek.com/670781/how-to-change-the-height-or-width-of-the-taskbar-on-windows-10/), unlock it and move it accordingly.